# Paypal Buyer Transaction Number and Seller Transaction Number Different

Tags: paypal, transactions

I am testing payments via paypal sandbox and I noticed that the txn_id passed via the ipn is different from the transaction number the "buyer" gets. I also noticed that the transaction number for both buyer and seller is different.

Is it a bug on the sandbox site? or just the way it is?
How am I able to track transactions pertaining to specific buyers later if both the transaction numbers are different?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's intended functionality -- the buyer and seller will have different transaction IDs.  It's the same way on the live site.

Comment: thanks for the reply, if thats the case, how were you able to resolve any tracking of transactions of some sort? coz the way I thought it was (I thought they have same transaction number) is that the customer or buyer just can call or email the seller and just give him the transaction number. Then the seller can react accordingly based on the transaction number the customer gave. But because they have different transaction numbers, how are you able to handle those situations? tips? thanks.

Comment: Internally, we have the two transaction IDs associated with each other.  We're able to tell what the seller's transaction ID is if we know the buyer's transaction ID, and vice versa.  That way, if a buyer opens up a dispute on a transaction, we can tell who the seller is and what transaction ID we should refer to when we communicate with the seller.  However, it's not something that we share with the outside world.  Your best bet is to use an invoice ID -- the buyer can see the invoice ID in their transaction details, and the seller can search their transactions based on the invoice ID.

Comment: @MattCole With a buyer account, looking at the transaction details, I see no invoice ID anywhere, only transaction ID.

Comment: @JoshBjelovuk The invoice ID has to be supplied with the transaction -- it's not something PayPal generates automatically.

Comment: If the recipient gives you their transaction ID, you can search for that in the PayPal web interface, and it will pull up the appropriate transaction on your end related to it. I am curious, is there an API to do this same thing?

Comment: I believe you can use GetTransactionDetails for that -- if you give it the buyer's transaction ID and your API credentials, it'll return the details on your side of the transaction (including your transaction ID).

Comment: Can this be done with REST API? Neither "/v2/checkout/orders/" nor "/v1/reporting/transactions" are able to find the buyer side TX.