# Grab transaction ID back from PayPal SDK

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying to figure out how to get the transaction ID for a payment made using the PayPal SDK. Here is what I have in my JS:

```
paypal.Buttons({

  createOrder: function(data, actions) {

    return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [{
            amount: {
                    value:    parseFloat( window.my_config.amount ),
                    currency: 'USD',
            },
            description: window.my_config.description
        }],
        commit: true
      });
  },


  onApprove: function(data, actions) {

    console.dir({ data: data, actions:actions });

    return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {

        console.log({ details: details });

        // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
        alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);

      });

    $('#AJAXloadingWrapper').show();

  }


}).render('#paypalWrapper');
```

This is what my debug comes back with:

[image]

I can't see the transaction ID in there anywhere. It should be 7CA44490MT363621L (going by the transid in my PayPal account)

How does one go about getting that? In the old system I used to use:

```
curl https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/L8EM97CXSYBJ2 -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer tokenstring"
```

But that doesn't work. I've tried just changing it to v2:

```
curl https://api.paypal.com/v2/payments/payment/L8EM97CXSYBJ2 -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxx"
```

...but all I get in response to that, is nothing (no error, but no output)

I have tried something based on:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/get-transaction/#on-the-server

```
sub get_proper_trans_id {
    my $token = encode_base64(qq|$config->{$config->{mode}}->{system_client_id}:$config->{$config->{mode}}->system_secret}|);
       $token =~ s/\n//g;
    my $trans_id = '50D311011N3466050';

    print qq|curl https://$config->{$config->{mode}}->{transaction_endpoint}/v2/payments/payment/$trans_id -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $token"\n|;

    my $results = `curl https://$config->{$config->{mode}}->{transaction_endpoint}/v2/payments/payment/$trans_id -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $token"`;
    my $json_vals = decode_json($results);

    use Data::Dumper;
    print Dumper($json_vals);
}
```

Which doesn't output anything (no errors either)

**UPDATE:** As suggested, I'm trying to use `purchase_units -> payments -> captures -> id` from the outputted results. The issue is that this seems wrong / different to what I'm expecting. When I log into my PayPal, I get:

```
0NP90326GE709501L
```

Yet the value in the returned data comes up as:

```
891170207E054363D
```

Why are these differently? FWIW I'm looking at this in my *personal* PayPal account (not the business it was sent to). The trans ID's should be the same for both the merchant and customer though, surely?

**UPDATE 2:** So after all this, I've found a thread that says PayPal intentionally give the buyer and seller different transaction ID's. What a PITA. So the alternative is to pass in a custom invoice_id, which we can cross reference with. All good - apart from I can't seem to do that either!

I've tried:

```
    return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [{
            amount: {
                    value:    parseFloat( window.my_config.amount ),
                    currency: 'USD',
            },
            description: window.my_config.description,
        }],
        invoice_id: invoice_id,
        commit: true
      });
  },
```

and also:

```
    return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [{
            amount: {
                    value:    parseFloat( window.my_config.amount ),
                    currency: 'USD',
            },
            description: window.my_config.description,
            invoice_id: invoice_id
        }],
        commit: true
      });
  },
```

But while they go through the process of making the payment ok, it comes back with:

```
Error: Order could not be captured
```

..when trying to run `return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {`

**UPDATE 3:**

I still can't get this to work. Is this how you pass a custom_id?

```
    return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [{
            amount: {
                    value:    parseFloat( window.my_config.amount ),
                    currency: 'USD',
                    custom_id: invoice_id
            },
            description: window.my_config.description
        }],
        commit: true
      });
```

I've tried it there, and also as below             `commit: true`, but it still doesn't work :( ("Order could not be captured" right after confirming payment)

Answer (score 2):

It's in purchase_units -> payments -> captures -> id

See a sample response at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders-capture-response

---

Once knowing the id, there's no reason you would need to do a separate GET request for this same data about it, but if you did the API call would be:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v2/#captures_get

Comment: thanks for that. In my test that gives me 9TE07281A3828142S, but the transid when I look at it on PayPal is: https://www.paypal.com/activity/payment/7CA44490MT363621L

Comment: I've added a bit more detail above. The trans ID still doesn't seem to match up with what I was expecting. The merchant and customer should both have the same transaction id, no?

Comment: oh interesting, I just found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18711131/paypal-buyer-transaction-number-and-seller-transaction-number-different . So it turns out PayPal intentionally give the buyer and seller different ID's. What a PITA! Why can't we just get the buyers ID? I want to include this in my email to the customer for the purchase :/

Comment: I've had a look, and it seems the only way around this is to include a custom invoice ID. The problem is, when I try and pass along invoice_id / custom_id, I get the " Order could not be captured" error :(

Comment: An invoice_id must be unique, never before used on the receiving account.  A custom_id can be anything

Comment: ah ok makes sense. Am I passing it in right though? I still get this error "Order could not be captured" (I've updated my opening question with the code I'm using) - **update 3**

Comment: @Preson - OMG, the issue for the `Order could not be captured` turned out to be that it wanted me to log out, and back in again!! WTF (I found this post about it: https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/SDKs/Sandbox-Account-Error-Order-could-not-be-captured/td-p/1761588 ). Sure enough, it works now and passes custom_id along. When I try it a 2nd time (even with a different custom_id, it borks and fails with that error)

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is the transaction id stored when you look at a paypal transaction in the paypal app. The following code shows you how to get the transaction ID using paypal javascript sdk. Go to the onApprove function and read the code:

```
<script>
  paypal.Buttons({

    // Sets up the transaction when a payment button is clicked
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [{
          
          amount: {
            value: '1'
          },
            
        }],
        application_context: {
            shipping_preference: "NO_SHIPPING",
        }
         
      });
    },

    // Finalize the transaction after payer approval
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {
        // Successful capture! For dev/demo purposes:
        //    console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));
           
            //The transaction ID is below this comment in the alert
            var transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];
           alert('Transaction '+ transaction.status + ': ' + transaction.id + '\n\nSee console for all available details');

        // When ready to go live, remove the alert and show a success message within this page. For example:
        // var element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
        // element.innerHTML = '';
        // element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>';
        actions.redirect('https://wwwwebsite.com/att_thanks.php?id=1640035591');
      });
    }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');

</script>
```

Comment: There's no use case for this. Doing things on the client side should be for informational purposes and exception/error handling only (nothing that would affect business logic/fulfillment). The capture ID that is returned is the receiving account's transaction ID, not the payer account's transaction ID.

Comment: @PrestonPHX I've actually found use in storing transaction id's to issue refunds to my users. I use javascript to populate a hidden input field with the transaction id and store it with the item purchase in the model database.

Comment: If you are storing information in the database, you should be capturing on a server not the client. https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server is the pattern to use.